# If I do a factory reset in Windows, will it remove the dual-booted linux completely?

Tags: format

I am going to sell my laptop, thus want to format it completely. If I do a format in windows using Reset this pc, will it remove all the Linux partition, and the bootloader will be fixed?

Comment: Probably not, but should make a mess of booting Linux.  For removing all data, would first make windows install disk, then google remove all data  from drive.  If very important data on drive that can't be allowed to be seen, replace drive with new one and keep/destroy old drive.  Windows license is tied to motherboard, not drive.

Comment: @crip659 can you tell me what to do then? Many websites say I need the windows installation disc for fixing the bootloader. But my laptop came pre-installed with the windows, thus I don't have the disc

Comment: Go to Microsoft.com and download same version of Windows you have(free), use their instructions for making disk/USB installer.  This if you can still boot into your Windows.  If using Linux only, need to install woeUSB or mkUSB(google how) to make windows installer USB.

Comment: You have two sections to your question, the first one re installing windows is easy.  The second removing your data is harder, a simple format is not enough.  Data on a drive is never erase, only hidden or overwritten.  Can make it so that it is very hard to find again.